# How to know the receiver and the sender of an MPI request

Tags: c++, boost, request, mpi

I wonder if there is a way to know the receiver process, the sender process and tag values of an MPI communication in boost.

Now, I have some processes which send/receive a lot of messages to/from each other. And, I have a collection of boost::mpi::request in the receiver side. This collection stores the request items that have been received. After the communication operations are completed, can I extract who the receiver process and the sender process are, from this collection? (I also need to know the tag value.) Or, should I change my strategy? Maybe having a collection of requests does not make sense?

Comment: Do you mean that once you complete the IRECV you want to find out who sent the data, or that you want to look at a Request object and figure out who it is to or from?

Comment: That was an either/or question, not a yes/no question. Anyway, if you meant the first option, Jonathan Dursi's answer below is what you want. If it's the second, you'll be much more disapointed.

Comment: The first one is exactly what I meant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That information is in the status after the request is completed, not in the request itself.

```
#include <boost/mpi.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>
namespace mpi = boost::mpi;

int main()
{
    mpi::environment env;
    mpi::communicator world;

    if (world.rank() == 0) {
        std::string msg, out_msg = "Hello from rank 0.";
        world.send(1, 17, out_msg);
    } else {
        mpi::request req[1];
        mpi::status stat[1];
        std::string rmsg;

        req[0] = world.irecv(mpi::any_source, mpi::any_tag, rmsg);
        mpi::wait_all(req, req + 1, stat);

        std::cout << "Got " << rmsg << std::endl;
        std::cout << "From   " << stat[0].source() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Tagged " << stat[0].tag() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's what i need. However, I'd like to add somethings for the next readers. If I define the status array with the size of 1, then I'm getting some MPI errors during the linking step. I couldn't figure out why it happens. So, I had to define it as mpi::status stat[2].

Comment: I didn't see any of those link errors.  wait_all has a super templat-y prototype: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost/mpi/wait_all.html  .  I am pretty new to boost so I cannot figure out why a status[1] array would be different from a status[2] array.  My linker problem with boost was simply that i had distribution libraries (g++ built 1.55) and home-rolled libraries (clang++ built 1.57) conflicting.  Perhaps something similar was going on with you?

Comment: Most probably, you are right. I am using a multi-agent simulation platform, called Repast HPC, and it also uses some other libraries. There might be a confliction among them. But now, I'm going on with status[2].

Comment: Well, the status array should be of the same size as the request array - if there's only one request being waited on, you don't actually need `wait_all()`, of course.  I just have one request/status here as an example.

Comment: There is not only one request. There are several requests which wait to be delivered. After isend() function is run, I want to cancel some of them which cannot be sent. So, I store these cancelled requests in a collection. And at the end of the program, I start to send these undelivered messages, again.

By the way, I use test_all() command, instead of wait_all(). So, if the message cannot be sent for a reason, then I cancel it.