# boost::mpi's irecv() returns non-initialized status objects

Tags: c++, boost, mpi

Im am receiving `boost::mpi` messages using the `irecv()` function. I have a waiting loop, that calls `test()` on the `request` object returned by `irecv` and, if the request finished, does something. However, trying to figure out the sender's rank, I get an exception:

```
boost::optional<T>::reference_type boost::optional<T>::get() [with T = boost::mpi::status; boost::optional<T>::reference_type = boost::mpi::status&]: Assertion `this->is_initialized()' failed.
```

Here is my code snippet:

```
mpi::request inc = world.irecv(mpi::any_source, MpiHandler::MPI_RESULT, pxl_results);
do {
    if(inc.test()) {
        // fails here, as the optional<status> returned by inc.test() is not initialized.
        world.send(inc.test().get().source(), MpiHandler::MPI_WORK, package);
        ...
    }
} while(...);
```

If I check for `inc.test().is_initialized()`, I find that the `optional<status>` is indeed uninitialized. What is happening here, and why can I not find out anything about my MPI sender? Is it possibly the `mpi::any_source` that doesn't play well with `irecv`?

---

Just to add: Typically, the sender and tag of an MPI message can be found out from the request object like outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27409094/169748).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm glad you worked it out, but maybe this will explain it further.

The issue is calling `req.test()` again after a successful call to `req.test()`. In *MPI - The Complete Reference: Volume 1, The MPI Core*:

> A request object is deallocated automatically by a successful call to MPI_WAIT or MPI_TEST.

Also, from the boost mpi documentation:

> optional< status > test();
>     Determine whether the communication associated with this request has completed successfully. If so, returns the status object describing the communication. Otherwise, returns an empty optional<> to indicate that the communication has not completed yet. **Note that once test() returns a status object, the request has completed and wait() should not be called.**

Therefore, after `if(req.test())` returns successfully a `boost::optional<mpi::status>` a subsequent call to `req.test()` will likely return an empty `optional<>` leading to your exception.

To see this we first create an example from Jonathan Dursi's hello world example in the linked answer:

```
#include <boost/mpi.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>
namespace mpi = boost::mpi;

int main()
{
  mpi::environment env;
  mpi::communicator world;

  if (world.rank() == 0) {
    std::string msg, out_msg = "Hello from rank 0.";
    world.send(1, 17, out_msg);
  } else {
    mpi::request req;
    std::string rmsg;

    req = world.irecv(mpi::any_source, mpi::any_tag, rmsg);
    do {
      if(req.test()) {
        // fails here, as the optional<status> returned by inc.test() is not initialized.
        std::cout << "From   " << req.test().get().source() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Got " << rmsg << std::endl;
        break;
      }
    } while(1);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Building and running this leads to the exception as expected:

```
[ronin:~/Documents/CPP] aichao% mpirun --hostfile hostfile -np 2 ./test_mpi_request
From   Assertion failed: (this->is_initialized()), function get, file /Users/Shared/Tools/boost_1_53_0/boost/optional/optional.hpp, line 631.
```

To fix this:

1. Call `req.test()` to return a `boost::optional<mpi::status>` object.
2. Test that `boost::optional` object to see if `req.test()` returned successfully and if successful, use the returned `mpi::status`.

The code:

```
#include <boost/mpi.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>
namespace mpi = boost::mpi;

int main()
{
  mpi::environment env;
  mpi::communicator world;

  if (world.rank() == 0) {
    std::string msg, out_msg = "Hello from rank 0.";
    world.send(1, 17, out_msg);
  } else {
    mpi::request req;
    std::string rmsg;

    req = world.irecv(mpi::any_source, mpi::any_tag, rmsg);
    do {
      boost::optional<mpi::status> stat = req.test();
      if (stat) {
        std::cout << "From   " << stat->source() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Got " << rmsg << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Tagged " << stat->tag() << std::endl;
        break;
      }
    } while(1);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Now, we have success:

```
[ronin:~/Documents/CPP] aichao% mpirun --hostfile hostfile -np 2 ./test_mpi_request
From   0
Got Hello from rank 0.
Tagged 17
```

Comment: As indicated in my answer, that was the issue. Thank you for the nice writeup.

Comment: This is an obvious deviation from the semantics of MPI requests as defined in the MPI standard and I would consider it a bug in boost::mpi. Once `MPI_Test` or `MPI_Wait` succeeds, it frees the request and resets the content of the request handle to `MPI_REQUEST_NULL`. Calling `MPI_Test` or `MPI_Wait` with a null request is a well-defined behaviour and the standard prescribes the content of the status object in that case.

Comment: @HristoIliev: I agree with you, but I don't believe the goal of `boost::mpi` is to fully preserve the semantics of MPI. As long as its API and usage patterns are well documented (you can argue that it is not), I would not consider this a bug, per se.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: The problem was that I called `test()` again, which apparently invalidates something. It works with

```
auto ret = inc.test();
if(ret) {
    // use ret->source()
}
```